# Java: Splitting up a massive 2D array into blocks that are a multiple of the machine's page size

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

The reason I'm doing this is so various different threads can do a certain computation simultaneously while receiving information from the same 2D array and writing to another, both of the same size.

Now, I understand how to simply break up the arrays into parts and assigning each a section to a thread. For example, I have 8 threads, and an 8x8 2D array. Each thread is responsible for gathering the information it needs from one 2D array, and then writing to it's own respective column in the other 2D array. Because there is no writing going on onto the first 2D array, there is no reason to set restrictions on the threads there, but it IS necessary to set restrictions on on the array that the threads are writing too. There isn't a problem with any of this on my part.

I am working on an assignment, and the programs run time is important. My instructor suggested we "make the block a thread deals with a multiple of the page size."

We are working with two 10 000 x 10 000 2D arrays, and the machines page sizes are 4Kib or 4096 bytes. My problem is I don't know how to utilize this information for my program. Right now I'm simply using boolean arrays but later on I'll be implementing it with arrays of chars.

Do I just calculate how many columns would equal a multiple of 4096 bytes, and then divide that among my 8 threads? How do I go about calculating the size of my 2D arrays?

Edit: As of now I have the program running fine it's just exceptionally slow. I should be creating anywhere between 30-60 generations a second, that is, 30-60 complete writes onto a full 10 000 x 10 000 array. Unfortunately I'm only getting ~8 writes a second. Right now each thread (out of 8) are writing on 12 500 x 10 000 equal sized blocks.

Comment: It may not be helpful with regard to you task, but in 15 years of dealing with Java, I've never encountered a situation where something like "the page size of a machine" actually made a performance difference (I'm not saying that there is none, only that it is *very* unlikely to make a difference at all (considering the thick abstraction layer of the JVM and the freedom that the JIT has in reorganizing things), and that it's unlikely that there are no other bottlenecks)

Comment: Note that there is a class of algorithms called "[cache oblivious algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm)", which are written in such a way as to break large problems down into subproblems which are ultimately small enough to fit in a cache page; however, they don't ever know the size of the cache page. Perhaps have a read about those, see if such an approach might help you.

Comment: Too vague about the actual data layout. You won't be able to optimize for TLB page size anyway, as you would need to have control over memory alignment of data structures (which you dont get in java). Just be wary to process arrays in a linear as possible fashion and beware of the arrays-of-arrays structure when there is more than one dimension (nesting loops the wrong way makes a sizable difference).

Answer (score 1):

The optimal layout really depends on the access pattern your processing exhibits. Generally you should aim to keep the memory access patterns as linearly as possible.

The first thing to be aware of is the way java treats multi-dimensional arrays as arrays of arrays; that means locality of access is best achieved by iterating the rightmost dimension in the innermost loop. Pulling out loop invariants can also help to reduce complexity. You arrive at something like this:

```
 int[][][] threeD = new int[10][10][10];
 for (int x=0; x<threeD.length; ++x) {
     int[][] twoD = threeD[x];
     for (int y=0; y<twoD.length; ++y) {
          int[] oneD = twoD[y];
          for (int z=0; z<oneD.length; ++z) {
              oneD[z] = // whatever
          }
      }
 }
```

From this follows you want to aim to distribute work not in "blocks", but continous slices, e.g. for a int[y=10000][x=10000] and 4 units of work, you would divide the outer dimension into 4 work units, not both dimensions into two each:

```
  Bad way to slice work:       More cache-friendly:
       111222                   111111
       111222                   222222
       333444                   333333
       333444                   444444
```

The TLB size (page size) is mostly irrelevant in schemes like this one. By keeping data access as linear as possible you automatically mostly minimize TLB misses as well, regardless of TLB entry count and page size. The aim here is to maximize the effectivity of burst memory access and/or speculative data prefetch.